# How to parse an C# assembly and extract every method

Tags: c#, methods, assemblies, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

For my application I'd like to parse through an assembly and extract every method and store the name of the method and the source code in one of my objects (I defined in my code).

where should I start to implement that?

EDIT: From the answers & comments i saw that it is not so easy to get source code from the assemblies. Then where should I start if I want to get source code from source code files that are not in my current solution (visual studio)?

Comment: What makes you think you can get source code out of an assembly?

Comment: I think before you start to ask a question like this, you need to learn a little bit more about a pretty fundamental programming/cs topic called "compilation" :P. C# isn't interpreted.

Comment: Well, Reflector does a pretty good job of it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The assembly *doesn't contain* the source code. You might be able to extract the IL, but without tools like reflector or ildasm that isn't especially helpful.

To obtain the *method names*, just something like:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var names = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 from method in type.GetMethods(
                   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
                 select type.FullName + ":" + method.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question since I dind't know that is not possible to extract source code from a assembly.

Answer (score 3):

**To retrieve this debugging information, use the [Common Compiler Infrastructure: Metadata API](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) project.**

This allows you to read the `.pdb` files (the files containing the debugging information like source file and line number).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but where are these pdb files?

Comment: They are in the `bin` folder. These are the files where your filenames and lines are stored.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - they are optional and make not exist, or may exist but only be available to the dev team (but not deployed)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find all the types.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to do that.

Then you can need to find all the methods for each types.

See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Getallmethodsfromaclass.htm) to do that.

If you need an example to bring it all together let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question since I dind't know that is not possible to extract source code from a assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the source code, but if you're trying to get information about the methods, you should use reflection.

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Static);
```